# 2 title bars in some gnome GTK apps

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gnome

i am having a strange issue, i have 2 title bars in some gnome apps at the top.

Here is a picture from the calendar app, look at the top:

[image]

And another one from the calculator app:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this issue or what might be causing it ?

My system info:

```
Operating Sysytem: Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon

Cinnamon Version: 5.4.12

Linux Kernel: 5.15.0-48-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by removing `gtk3-nocsd`, i did the following:

1. `sudo apt remove gtk3-nocsd`
2. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

The inner or lower title is the CSD -- Client-Side Decoration.  What is *supposed* to happen is that the application tells the window manager not to put its own, standard, decoration, on the window.  For some reason, in your situation, the window manager is ignoring that request and adding its own (outer/upper) title bar.  Are you using a non-standard window manager, or have you inadvertently made some setting to the window manager, telling it always to decorate/reparent its windows?

Comment: I don't know, how can i check these settings ? Is there a place where these configurations reside ? Notice that not all apps does this.

Comment: Without having access to your computer, it's very difficult to say.  If you are really desperate, you could work stepwise towards the file that contains the errant configuration setting thus:  *(1)* log out of your desktop.  *(2)* log in via a CLI (ctrl-alt-F2).  *(3)* mv .config dot-config.  *(4)* ctrl-alt-F7  *(5)* log in graphically and observe whether or not the effect is still present.  *(6)* etc.  ... if you don't see where I'm going with this, don't do it as you will cause more harm than good and you'll have to ask someone to assist you in person.

Comment: I think this happened after i executed the command `sudo apt install gtk*`